# Styling of template tags in Django

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to style my register form but since it uses template tags to merge in the fields to fill in I'm not sure how to do it.

I want my register form to look like my login form. The code for the login form is here:

```
{% extends 'rango/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block body_block %}

<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}

<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text" required autofocus=""/>
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="id_password" name="password" type="password" required />

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit" />Sign in</button>
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

... and the code for my register form looks like this:

```
{% extends 'rango/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <div class="container">
            {% if registered %}
            <p>Thank you for registering.</p>

            <p><a href="/rango/login/">Login</a> when you are ready to rango.</p>
            {% else %}
            <form class="form-signin span8" id="user_form" method="post" action="/rango/register/"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign up here</h2>
                <!-- Display each form here -->

                {% for field in user_form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}<br />
                {{ field }}<br/>
                {% endfor %}

                {% for field in profile_form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}<br />
                {{ field }}<br />
                {% endfor %}


                <br />
                <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So the question is "How can I style the register form when it uses template tags to show the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining your form class, you can add css attributes this way:

```
username_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

Comment: @AndersHasselstrøm glad to help :) would appreciate if you can "accept the answer"